# How do I use R extension for visual studio code with R module on cluster

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I'd like to use the R extension for visual studio code on a computing cluster where I typically issue a command like "load module R" in a shell before starting a new R session (from that shell). I have installed the R extension for visual studio code on the login node of my computing cluster, but it seems that, when I click the "R: (not attached)" text in the lower right hand corner of my VS code window, I see two error messages:

1. Could not find R path. Please check r.term and r.path setting.
2. Cannot find R for creating R terminal. Change setting r.rterm.linux to R path.

How do I use the vscode R extension in this setting? is there a settings file where I should instruct vscode to issue a "load module R" command?

I appreciate your suggestions. Thanks!